# How to install open connect client on Amazon linux

Tags: amazon-linux, openconnect, amazon

```
sudo yum list all | grep openconnect
    NetworkManager-openconnect.x86_64       0.8.6.0-3.el6                  epel     
    openconnect.i686                        7.07-2.el6                     epel     
    openconnect.x86_64                      7.07-2.el6                     epel     
    openconnect-devel.i686                  7.07-2.el6                     epel     
    openconnect-devel.x86_64                7.07-2.el6                     epel
```

Tried to install NetworkManager-openconnect

```
sudo yum install NetworkManager-openconnect
```

Ended up in dependencies error.

```
Error: Package: NetworkManager-openconnect-0.8.6.0-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgnome-keyring.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: NetworkManager-openconnect-0.8.6.0-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: NetworkManager >= 1:0.8.1
Error: Package: NetworkManager-openconnect-0.8.6.0-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: openconnect-7.07-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpcsclite.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: NetworkManager-openconnect-0.8.6.0-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgconf-2.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: NetworkManager-openconnect-0.8.6.0-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libnm-util.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: NetworkManager-openconnect-0.8.6.0-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: NetworkManager-openconnect-0.8.6.0-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: NetworkManager-openconnect-0.8.6.0-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libnm-glib-vpn.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: NetworkManager-openconnect-0.8.6.0-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libnm-glib.so.2()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Can you please try to help me to install occlient on Amazon linux?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this problem by building the openconnect client from source instead of installing it via `yum`.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an old issue but I had the same problem when trying to install `openconnect` with yum on an EC2 instance running amazon linux 2. I managed to fix it by enabling epel with `amazon-linux-extras`.

- `amazon-linux-extras install epel`
- `amazon-linux-extras enable epel`

Then installing epel release for yum:

- `yum clean metadata`
- `yum install epel-release`

and finally installing open connect:

- `yum install openconnect`